# How to load data value input correspond to value of option tag when an option tag is selected?

Tags: magento2

I set data successfully in option tag but dont know how to show data in input correspond to option tag which is selected.

Here is my code:

Index.phtml

```
<?php
$member = $block->getMembers();
?>
    <select id="member-id">
        <option selected disabled>Select an ID</option>
        <?php foreach ($member as $p): ?>
            <option value="<?= $p['member_id'] ?>">
                <?= $p['member_id'] ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <div>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="value of name">
        <br>
        <label>Address</label>
        <input type="text" name="address" id="address" value="value of address">
        <br>
        <label>Phone</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="value of phone">
    </div>
```

Block/Member.php

```
class Member extends Template
{
    ...
    public function getMembers()
    {
        return $this->customerFactory->create()->getData();
    }
    ...
}
```